# Are questions of the form "Can X be done with Y" on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422455/does-datanucleus-support-mixing-inheritence-strategies-when-using-jpa-annotation) about whether DataNucleus (an ORM) can use different inheritance mappings at different points in the inheritance hierarchy when using its JPA annotations. I'm not sure if these kinds of questions are on topic for Stack Overflow. I believe these questions can be very valuable to people searching for these issues, but they also tend to have very short answers with little substance.

I'm also not sure how the premise of such questions affects whether they are good questions. Using my question as an example again, the premise is that the JPA does not mandate support for the feature in question, and as such many implementations do not support it, but DataNucleus in particular is also an implementation of JDO, which does mandate it. For comparison, I have seen many questions asking whether Hibernate, another ORM, supports this feature, but they are just the bare question and don't have a premise like my example. Some such questions:

- [How to mix inheritance strategies with JPA annotations and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915026/how-to-mix-inheritance-strategies-with-jpa-annotations-and-hibernate)
- [Hibernate mixing inheritance strategies for multi-level hierachy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504591/hibernate-mixing-inheritance-strategies-for-multi-level-hierachy)

By the way, is the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag appropriate when I want to discuss a question that hasn't been posted yet?

Comment: Questions which can be answered with just a "Yes" or "No" can be on-topic, but aren't particularly useful. Perhaps you should ask "How can I do X with Y?" so that answerers have more content to work with. Just make sure that you do your research, show your research, and show your attempt.

Comment: @4castle with my question (which I just asked, see edit to this question), there's not much more to the answer than a yes or no, unless there is a big "gotcha"; How to do it given knowledge that it can be done is straightforward. As for an attempt, the setup for making an attempt may be more difficult than I expect, hence I wanted to ask first in this instance.

Comment: I don't know anything about DataNucleus, but generally questions of the form "Does this code work?" aren't well received, because it implies that you haven't even tried it. You should show your attempt and any errors or unexpected results. As I said, I'm not experienced in that technology, so I can only critique the manner you asked the question in.

Comment: In my opinion, questions along the lines of "can I do *x* with *y*?" come down to a response of "well, did you try?" -- which I would generally vtc as too broad because it's not about a specific problem and shows a clear lack of research (in this case, attempt to implement the hypothetical in question.) Consider, for example, a similarly formulated question: "Can I perform integer arithmetic with Java?"

Comment: see also: [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)